# Sort array output python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, arraylist

```
array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
```

I'm trying to write a code to sort the array

Comment: replace `_,x` with `x,_`

Comment: what's `I'm trying to write a code to sort the array in the format of another array` meaning?

Comment: X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [ "i", "a","e"]
Z = [x for x,_ in sorted(zip(X,Y))]
print(Z)


While printing this i wanted the output of Z to be ["a","e","i"] but i'm getting ['a', 'b', 'c']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension, you can do the following:

```
array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
array2 = [ "c", "a","b"]

Z = [b for b in array1 if any(b in a for a in array2)]
print(Z)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what "sort the array in the format of another array" meams?  If you mean sort a subset of the aray so that the order in the subset is the same as the order in the array, you can  use something like

sorted(array2,key = lambda k:array1.index(k))

which will sort array2  so that any two elements of array2 are in the same order as in array 1.  Note "subset" is needed.  This will fail if there is an element of array2 that is not in array1